# I am trying to arrange three 3 numbers in ascending manner using if statement, but this doesn't work for the third number. What can be done about it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, temp;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a > b)
    {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    else if (b > c)
    {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }
    else if (c > a)
    {
        temp = c;
        c = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

If I put 8,6,3, the output comes 6,8,3. It doesn't change the last number. I am trying to arrange three 3 numbers in ascending manner using if statement, but this doesn't work for the third number. What can be done about it?

Comment: You probably should drop all the `else` keywords. If you enter the first `if` body, you still need to check afterwards whether b and c are in sequence. In your code you only enter one block but you might need to enter all three of them. After that change, your third condition is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It easiest if you first find the smallest, then make sure the remaining two are correct :

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, temp;

    int ret = scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (ret != 3) {
        printf("scanf() error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // get smallest into a
    if ((b < a) && (b < c)) {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    } else if ((c < a) && (c < b)) {
        temp = a;
        a = c;
        c = temp;
    }

    // a is smallest, check b and c
    if (c < b) {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A professional answer would check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: true, but that is not related to his question

Comment: You should still add it IMHO: not checking the return value is a bad habit.

Comment: added `scanf()` return value check

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,temp;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(b>c)
    {
        temp=b;
        b=c;
        c=temp;
    }
    if(a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}


What about this code? This seems to work.

Comment: @Maryam that is what I mentioned in my comment above. Should work fine.

Comment: How can it be done using **for loop** so that I don't have to write lengthy code?

Comment: if you place the numbers in an `array`, you can look up any number of `sorting algorithms`.  `Bubble sort` is a simple algorithm that is a good place to start.  And is essentially the same as the code you linked in your above comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if` instead of `else if` as you want to compare a with b, b with c and a with c (the three and not only one of them). Moreover, as you are moving the numbers you have to take into account where they are moved for the last comparison. And your third condition was wrong. So this should be what you are trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b, c, temp;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a > b){
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (b > c){
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
        if (a > b){
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
    }
    else if (a > c){
        temp = c;
        c = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of if else if structure, In your case it is not working for third number because the execution will reach to else if part only when the if condition is false.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
int a,b,c,temp;
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
if(a>b)  //evaluates to true.
{
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
else if(b>c)  // not able to execute.
{
    temp=b;
    b=c;
    c=temp;
}
else if(c>a)  // not able to execute
{
    temp=c;
    c=a;
    a=temp;
}
printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
return 0;
}

a = 8
b = 6
c = 3

checking a>b evaluates to true hence swapped
now:

a = 6  // your output
b = 8
c = 3
```

you may need to go over the concept of if else structure once again

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,temp;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(b>c)
    {
        temp=b;
        b=c;
        c=temp;
    }
    if(a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}


What about this code? This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a ,b,c;
    printf("Enter the number : \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    if((a>b)&&(a>c))
    {
        if(b>c)
           printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
        else
           printf("%d %d %d",a ,c,b);
     }

     else if((b>c)&&(b>a))
     {
         if(c>a)
            printf("%d %d %d",b,c,a);
         else
            printf("%d %d %d",b,a,c);
     }

     else if((c>a)&&(c>b))
     {
         if(a>b)
           printf("%d %d %d",c,a,b);
         else
            printf("%d %d %d",c,b,a);
     }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: can you indent your code please ? It's really difficult to read right now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an array instead of three individual variables. Then use `qsort` for getting the input sorted.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Compare function for qsort
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  if (*(int*)p1 < *(int*)p2) return -1;
  if (*(int*)p2 < *(int*)p1) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3];
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]) != 3) exit(1);

    // Sort the input
    qsort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int), sizeof(int), cmp);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,temp,min;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(c<a)
    {
        min=c;
        c=b;
        b=a;
        a=min;
    }
    else if(c>a && b<c) {
        min=c;
         c=b;
         b=min;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

you are comparing using `else if`, if any one condition satisfies it won't execute the other `else` condition.

Comment: You swap `b` and `c` without checking which one is larger.

Comment: you are correct i altered my code now it is perfect.

Comment: Nope. 1,2,3 => 1,3,2;  1,2,1 => 1,2,1.